# how to loop a Rock Paper Scissor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing the RPS project and I am finally able to declare who is the winner of the round, and now I want to loop the round in 5 so I can declare the overall winner, but I don't know how to apply it to the for loop, can you help me?

Here's my code. Please don't be hard on me I'm a beginner haha.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  function getComputerChoice() {
    if (choice === 1) {
      return "ROCK";
    } else if (choice === 2) {
      return "PAPER";
    } else if (choice === 3) {
      return "SCISSOR";
    }
  }


  function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (computerSelection == "ROCK" && playerSelection == "ROCK") {
      return "Tie!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "ROCK" && playerSelection == "PAPER") {
      return "You win!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "ROCK" && playerSelection == "SCISSOR") {
      return "You lose!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "PAPER" && playerSelection == "PAPER") {
      return "Tie";
    } else if (computerSelection == "SCISSOR" && playerSelection == "SCISSOR") {
      return "Tie";
    } else if (computerSelection == "PAPER" && playerSelection == "ROCK") {
      return "You lose!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "SCISSOR" && playerSelection == "ROCK") {
      return "You win!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "PAPER" && playerSelection == "SCISSOR") {
      return "You win!";
    } else if (computerSelection == "SCISSOR" && playerSelection == "PAPER") {
      return "You win!";
    }
  }

  let player = prompt("pick", '');
  const playerSelection = player.toUpperCase();
  const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  const playRoundResult = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

  console.log(`Player pick: ${playerSelection}`);
  console.log(`Computer pick: ${computerSelection}`);

}
let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0;



function roundScore() {

  if (playRoundResult == "Tie!") {
    computerScore += 0;
  } else if (playRoundResult == "You win!") {
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (playRoundResult == "You lose!") {
    computerScore += 1;
  }

}

console.log(`Computer: ${computerScore}`);
console.log(`Player: ${playerScore}`);
```

this is my my current progress, I want the the score to increment and to loop the prompt 5 times and declare the overall winner.

Current console.log:

[image: console]

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```js
let playRoundResult;
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const playGame = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    function getComputerChoice() {
      if (choice === 1) return 'ROCK';
      if (choice === 2) return 'PAPER';
      return 'SCISSOR';
    }

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
      const win = (computerSelection === 'ROCK' && playerSelection === 'PAPER') ||
        (computerSelection === 'SCISSOR' && playerSelection === 'ROCK') ||
        (computerSelection === 'PAPER' && playerSelection === 'SCISSOR') ||
        (computerSelection === 'SCISSOR' && playerSelection === 'PAPER');
      if (computerSelection === playerSelection) return 'Tie!';
      if (win) {
        playerScore++;
        return 'You win!';
      }
      computerScore++;
      return 'You lose!';
    }

    let player = prompt('pick', '');
    const playerSelection = player.toUpperCase();
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    playRoundResult = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

    console.log(`Player pick: ${playerSelection}`);
    console.log(`Computer pick: ${computerSelection}`);
  }
}

playGame();

console.log(`Computer: ${computerScore}`);
console.log(`Player: ${playerScore}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep your code intact as much as possible, but at least some basic reorganization was required:

- I use on array for game elements, and always refer to it with indices, you can see that this simplifies a lot
- I hate to see function definitions within normal code flow ...
- if player enters typo, he loses ...

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === -1) {
    computerScore += 1;
    return "You lose!";
  }

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return "Tie!";
  } else if (computerSelection === (playerSelection + 2) % 3) {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You win!";
  } else {
    computerScore += 1;
    return "You lose!";
  }
}

const choices = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSOR"];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;


for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  let player = prompt(`round ${i + 1} pick:`, '');
  const playerSelection = choices.indexOf(player.toUpperCase());
  const computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  const playRoundResult = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  console.log(playRoundResult);

  console.log(`Player pick: ${choices[playerSelection]}`);
  console.log(`Computer pick: ${choices[computerSelection]}`);

}

console.log(`Computer: ${computerScore}`);
console.log(`Player: ${playerScore}`);
```

Main trick to avoid that nasty decision tree lies here: 
 `if (computerSelection === (playerSelection + 2) % 3)`

What it means? With this, simple numeric trick, I check that computer selection has an index lower by one corresponding to player selection. Based on the order of elements in the array, this already indicates that the computer loses in this case.